# Putting Labels before Radio in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new with Bootstrap. I created a selection of radio buttons with labels, but by default the radio buttons are placed first before the labels. I want to have the labels first, before the radio buttons.

This is my code:

```
<div class="radio">
                        <label class="radio inline control-label">
                        Settled
                        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio_Cancelled" value="option1" checked>
                        </label>
                    </div>


                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio inline control-label">
                    Cancelled
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio_Cancelled" value="option2">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio inline control-label">
                    Postponed
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio_Postponed" value="option3">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio inline control-label">
                    Re-book (funds not sent)
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio_Rebook" value="option4">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="radio">
                    <label class="radio inline control-label">
                    Funded Manually
                    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio_FundedManually" value="option5">
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Can anyone help me? It would be much appreciated if you can assist me with this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Bootstrap floats them to the left, what you could do is add this line to your CSS.

```
.radio input[type="radio"] {
  float:none;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

Here is a bootply for you -- http://bootply.com/107892
change the margin-left to suit your taste.

Comment: how can i align all the radio in 1 place? the labels and the radio buttons should be aligned justified.

Comment: @Nooblike You could change `float:none;` to `float:right;` and wrap all of the radio buttons in a div element, and set that elements width. Another possible way would be to use tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot natewiley. Appreciate your help. Cheers!